# Regex: Capturing repeating group of groups (Perl)

Tags: regex, perl

In Perl, I am trying to capture the words as tokens from the following example strings (there will always be at least one word):

```
"red"               ==>    $1 = 'red';
"red|white"         ==>    $1 = 'red'; $2 = 'white';
"red|white|blue"    ==>    $1 = 'red'; $2 = 'white'; $3 = 'blue';
etc.
```

The pattern I see here is: WORD, followed by n sets of "|WORD" [n >= 0]

So from that, I have:

**/(\w+)((?:\|)(\w+)*)/**

Which, to my understanding will always match the first WORD, and if a |WORD pair exists, capture that as many times as needed.

This doesn't work though, and I've tried several versions like:

**/^(\w+)(\|(\w+))*$/**

... what am I missing?

Comment: You can't do it like this. When you repeat a capture group the previous match is overwritten by the new one (at each repetition). Why don't you just use split?

Comment: You can achieve that with Python PyPi regex, .NET Regex (CapureCollection) and there is an option to get the captures in Boost regex library.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: You can also achieve that with Perl regexes -- just not the way the OP is trying to.

Comment: Perl 6 is even cooler with its `%` modifier

Answer (score 2):

Your first regex is actually wrong — the `*` is in the wrong place — but I'll focus on your second regex, which is correct:

```
/^(\w+)(\|(\w+))*$/
```

The problem is that this regex has three capture groups: `(\w+)`, `(\|(\w+))`, and `(\w+)`. So it will populate, at most, three match variables: `$1`, `$2`, and `$3`. Each match variable corresponds to a single corresponding capture group. Which is not what you want.

What you should do instead is use `split`:

```
my @words = split /\|/, "red|white|blue";

# now $words[0] is 'red', $words[1] is 'white', $words[2] is 'blue'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

Edit: So is it not possible to do this with regex? 
What about: /^(\w+)(\|\w+)*?$/

Comment: @JesseWalton: The number of capture-groups in a regex is a static/lexical property of the regex, and doesn't depend on the string it's matching against. If you need a variable number of capture-groups, then a single regex match is not for you. (`'red|white|blue' =~ m/^(\w+)(\|(\w+))*$/` is like writing `$1 = 'red'; $2 = '|white'; $3 = 'white'; $2 = '|blue'; $3 = 'blue'`. It keeps reusing the same capture variables.)